# NumberFormatException error in my code.I made sure that every file aren't empty

Tags: java, swing, integer, numberformatexception

I am creating a daily saving log. While creating I got this **NumberFormatException**.I  need some help to complete the project.

here's the code I'm working on.

```
package app;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class Application {
    
     BufferedWriter log = null;
     BufferedWriter bal = null;

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Appilcation window = new Appilcation();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Appilcation() {
        try {
            initialize();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private void initialize() throws IOException,NumberFormatException{
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 420);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

         
            log= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Log.txt")));//writer for log
            bal= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("bal.txt")));// "      "  bal
            Scanner File = new Scanner(new File("bal.txt"));
           //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
          // Date date = new Date(); 
           
           
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 102));
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 420);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblDdmmyyyy = new JLabel("dd/mm/yyyy");
        lblDdmmyyyy.setFont(new Font("ARCADE", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblDdmmyyyy.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblDdmmyyyy.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblDdmmyyyy.setBounds(10, 11, 100, 29);
        panel.add(lblDdmmyyyy);
        
        JLabel lblHh = new JLabel("hh:mm:ss");
        lblHh.setFont(new Font("ARCADE", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblHh.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblHh.setBounds(324, 11, 100, 29);
        panel.add(lblHh);
        
        JButton btnAddSavings = new JButton("Add");
        btnAddSavings.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 0));
        btnAddSavings.setFont(new Font("ARCADE", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnAddSavings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //something is not ryt here
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String Add=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(panel,"Enter Amount to be added");
                String s=/*sdf.format(date)+**/"   "+Add+"(Added)";
                String Bal="";
                while(File.hasNextLine())
                     Bal=File.nextLine(); 
                int aa=Integer.parseInt(Bal);
                int bb =Integer.parseInt(Add);
                int sum=aa+bb;
                
                    try {
                        bal.write(sum+"\n");
                        log.write(s+"\n");
                        
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
              
               
               
               
            }
        });
        btnAddSavings.setBounds(138, 150, 173, 64);
        panel.add(btnAddSavings);
        
        JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        btnRemove.setBackground(new Color(255, 127, 80));
        btnRemove.setFont(new Font("ARCADE", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnRemove.setBounds(138, 225, 173, 64);
        panel.add(btnRemove);
        
        JButton btnIdeas = new JButton("ideas");
        btnIdeas.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        btnIdeas.setFont(new Font("ARCADE", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        btnIdeas.setBounds(138, 300, 173, 34);
        panel.add(btnIdeas);
        
        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Log");
        btnExit.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 255));
        btnExit.setBounds(138, 345, 71, 23);
        panel.add(btnExit);
        
        JButton btnExit_1 = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit_1.setBackground(new Color(204, 204, 255));
        btnExit_1.setBounds(240, 345, 71, 23);
        panel.add(btnExit_1);
        
        JLabel lblRs = new JLabel("0   Rs.");
        lblRs.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        lblRs.setFont(new Font("Bebas", Font.PLAIN, 23));
        lblRs.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblRs.setBounds(105, 81, 239, 58);
        panel.add(lblRs);
        
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        panel_1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        panel_1.setBounds(105, 81, 239, 58);
        panel.add(panel_1);
        bal.close();
        log.close();
        
    }
    }
```

and the error message :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     at
> java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)   at
> java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)    at
> app.Appilcation$2.actionPerformed(Appilcation.java:113)   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

things I tried:

-> made sure all the files are not empty.

little help here plss.

Comment: I think the issue you have is that the path to your file is not correctly set. Scanner(new File("bal.txt")) probably reference a file which doesn't exist. Make sure to use the correct path to the file

Comment: Please tell us which line is 113.

Comment: Java naming conventions have variables, methods, and parameters start with a lower case letter; classes start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

The  problem seems to be that one file has an empty line. Before parsing Bal, Check if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the following snippet related to the non-validated inputs

1. `Add` may be empty or not a number when returned from the `JOptionPane`
2. `Bal` may be empty: actually `Bal` is assigned the *last line* from the file.  So, file may be non-empty, but it may contain a trailing empty line and thus `Bal` is `""`;

```java
    String Add=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(panel,"Enter Amount to be added");
    String s=/*sdf.format(date)+**/"   "+Add+"(Added)";
    String Bal="";
    while(File.hasNextLine())
        Bal=File.nextLine(); 
    int aa=Integer.parseInt(Bal);
    int bb =Integer.parseInt(Add);
    int sum=aa+bb;
```

So you may want to implement a separate method to parse numbers without fail:

```java
    private static int getNumber(String s) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            res = Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to parse number from '" + s + "', " + ex.getMessage());
            res = 0;
        }
        return res;
    }
// ...
    int aa = getNumber(Bal);
    System.out.printf("DEBUG: Bal='%s' -> aa=%d%n", Bal, aa);
    int bb = getNumber(Add);
    System.out.printf("DEBUG: Add='%s' -> bb=%d%n", Add, bb);
```

Comment: Failed to parse number from '', For input string: ""

Comment: @TheFox-CodersAcademy, you get the message, the app should not crash in this place.  To get rid of the error, you have to identify the invalid input by debugging the application using log messages as in the updated answer or setting breakpoints in your IDE.